# Delphi 11.3 Professional new install: no Subversion integration

Tags: delphi-11-alexandria

This morning I installed Rad Studio 11.3 Professional. Opening a project, I found  Subversion integration nonfunctional, despite the path to the client (TortoiseSVN) being set.

Copying the subversion folder from an 11.0 installation into the 11.3 bin folder and setting the Tools->Options->Version Control->Subversion->Subversion Path fixed the issue, but it's a kludge which shouldn't be needed. When I installed Rad Studio 11.0 Professional last year, Subversion support was enabled by default.

Am I missing a step in the installation? Or is there now a separate component for integrated SVN support? I do notice that in 11.0, there is no 'Subversion Path" under Tools->Options->Version Control->Subversion; this seems to be new.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with version 11.3, Subversion support is no longer built into the IDE, and instead must be configured manually by setting the Tools->Options->Version Control->Subversion->Subversion Path to the bin folder of a supported x86 client. Supported clients are VisualSVN 1.14.2 and WANDisco 1.14.1.

My solution was to download the archived Apache SVN binaries from the VisualSVN site, extract them into a subfolder named "Apache-SVN" under the "%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%" folder, and then set the IDE's "Subversion Path" to the "%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%\Apache-SVN\bin".

For further details, consult [Subversion Integration in the IDE](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/Subversion_Integration_in_the_IDE).